# Why is my TabItem custom control not showing up in the TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I made a custom control called **SmartTabItem**, currently just the default implementation:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestControl.Controls
{
    public class SmartTabItem : TabItem
    {
        static SmartTabItem()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SmartTabItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SmartTabItem)));
        }
    }
}
```

I include it in my **TabControl** like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestControl.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestControl.Controls"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <TabControl>
            <controls:SmartTabItem Header="One">content of one</controls:SmartTabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Two">content of two</TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Three">content of three</TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

But only tabs "Two" and "Three" are displayed. **Why isn't the SmartTabItem showing up in the TabControl if it inherits from TabItem?**

Comment: I was just having the exact same problem.  Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the default style for a `TabItem` on your `SmartTabItem`, modify the code like this:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SmartTabItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TabItem)));
```

This will tell the wpf system to use the `TabItem`'s default style for your tab items. Otherwise, your tab item is truly lookless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing because you've overridden its default style, but have not provided a style for it in Generic.xaml. Try commenting out this line to test:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SmartTabItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SmartTabItem)));
```